# Get JSON content from website after login

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer

I want to read JSON from a website. Before I get the data in JSON format I need to login to create a session. The second URL must be opened in the same session.

My code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$requestUri = "LOGIN_URL"
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($requestUri)

$requestUri = "JSON_URL"
$ie.Navigate($requestUri)
while ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
```

I tried to get the content with something like `$ie.Document.Body` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you take a look at [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) and [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)?  Might be easier than trying to manipulate an IE object.

Comment: Works for `$requestUri = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/53728382/3439404'` (this page).

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. What result did you expect? What result did you actually get? Were there errors? If so, what did they say?

Comment: First try to check that after getting logged in on that site, Are you able to get your JSON content on that page? If yes, Than after try to fetch it via code. Try to check the web page with inspect element to fetch specific data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutio, the following will return json:

```
$ie.Document.documentelement.innertext
```

Comment: I suggest you to mark your solution as an accepted answer for this thread may help other community members in future. Thanks for your understanding.